# Calling another function within Foundation's Reveal with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, zurb-foundation

I haven't seen anything regarding my issue here: after opening up the modal, I have a button that when clicked, it calls another function but nothing happens. This is a slimmed down example with React:

```
_sayHi: function() {
 console.log("Hi");
}

_loop: function() {
 var foo = this.props.bar.map( function(a,b){
  return(
   <div key={a.id}>
     <button className="small button success" data-open="exampleModal1">Open</button>
     <div className="reveal" id="exampleModal1" data-reveal="">
       <h3>Are you sure</h3>
       <p>This action cannot be undone and it's final!</p>
       <button className="close-button" data-close="" aria-label="Close modal" type="button">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
       </button>
       <div className="f__right flex">
          <button className="small button success" onClick={this._sayHi}>Hi</button>
          <button className="small button alert" data-close="">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  )
 }.bind(this));
  return(<div>{foo}</div>)
},

render: function() {
 return(<div>{this._loop()}</div>)
}
```

If I should move the function button outside the modal, the button works as it should. Do I need to do something special?

What I want: Open the modal (which works), then click a button to call a function (does nothing, nothing in console).

**Edit:**

I see why this is not working. Foundation's Reveal is not mounted inside the prop, it's outside so `this` is not being referred to my Component:

```
<div data-react-class="FooBar" data-react-props="{...}"></div> // React component
<div class="reveal-overlay></div> // Modal when closed
```

I guess foundation's modal is not ideal in this case?

Comment: Do you have any error message printed on the console when clicking the button ?

Comment: No. Nothing at all. I wish I got an error.

Comment: Could you post your the whole component code ?

Comment: Too many nested components. It's huge to post. With what I have posted should be easily recreated; I have and same.

Comment: Did you correctly write your example ? Because for what I'm seeing, your `map` method returns adjacents jsx elements, that it's not valid and should therefore throw an error a compile time. Maybe you're bundle is not recreated and your still rendering some old bundle without the good components.

Comment: Ok, I've added the missing `divs`, but button not calling the function. I've just tried another rails app, `rails new demo` and same. It must be Foundation.

Comment: Try to set only the minimum code, if your `map` function only returns `<button className="small button success" onClick={this._sayHi}>Hi</button>`, what happens ?

Comment: It's not the loop. If I just have the modal in the component's render, same issue: modal pops up, hit the `hi` button...nothing.

Answer (score 0):

buttons will try to submit by default maybe you could try the following

```
_sayHi: function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 console.log("Hi");
}
```

You should also wrap the return from your map function in a single div like so

```
_loop: function() {
  var foo = this.props.bar.map( function(a,b){
  return(
    <div>
      <button className="small button success" data-open="exampleModal1">Open</button>
      <div className="reveal" id="exampleModal1" data-reveal="">
        <h3>Are you sure</h3>
        <p>This action cannot be undone and it's final!</p>
        <button className="close-button" data-close="" aria-label="Close modal" type="button">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <div className="f__right flex">
          <button className="small button success" onClick={this._sayHi}>Hi</button>
          <button className="small button alert" data-close="">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )}.bind(this));
  return(<div>{foo}</div>)
}
```

Comment: Tried. Nothing. It's not calling the function and that's the issue.

Comment: @Sylar Made an edit to my answer, sometimes react does not like when you return elements without an enclosing div (or other parent element)

Comment: Cool. Would that be the case? Because having the button outside the modal does work. Ok, I'll get this a go later as I've just headed outside. Ill report later.

Comment: @Sylar It could also be that some other element is hijacking the event and that why it works outside the modal - could try to set the z-index on that button too

Comment: In the chrome dev tools, under event listeners, the button points to an empty function: `function emptyFunction() {}` Why?

Comment: I think foundation is manipulating the DOM and react is not able to keep track so I think for this to work you'll need to access the DOM directly

Comment: I see. I've tried react modal and that seemed to work great but would like to use foundation's reveal. I'll play more with this later. Thanks.

Comment: maybe try to use something like this --> https://github.com/akiran/react-foundation-apps that wraps foundation in react components?